# Obtain a git repository's tree elsewhere via --work-tree while keeping --git-dir repository unmodified

Tags: git

Given a checked out repository under `/orig-git` the command

```
git --git-dir=/orig-git/.git --work-tree=/copy checkout -f REV
```

results in a checked out tree in `/copy/` representing the state at `REV` but **also** modifies the `/orig-git` repository to point to `REV` (while leaving the files themselves untouched). Is is possible to just obtain a copy of revision `REV` in `/copy` but without duplicating the information in `/orig-git/.git` via clone, fetch or just plain copying this .git repository over?

Essentially I want to do a read-only operation regarding the git repo information, but still modify/write the checkout out tree elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the simplest option is just to clone the repository:

```
git clone -l /orig/git /copy
```

Now you have a copy of the repository that you can modify as much as you want without affecting the original. If you actual want to update the original with your changes from `/copy`, you can `git push` them back if `/orig` is properly configured.

If you are concerned about space used by having a second copy of the repository, the `-l` flag means that whenever possible, "files under the .git/objects/ directory are hardlinked to save space when possible" (from `git-clone(1)`).

Comment: Great pointer, looking through the git clone manpage near `-l` I found `-s` (which forgoes touching all the objects/ inodes by not even hardlinking and just creating `.git/objects/info/alternates`) and cloning with -n (i.e. no checkout). Then I can just do a `git checkout -f REV` with only minimal copy operations. I was too focused on disecting the checkout manpage.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [git-archive](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive)

> `git archive --format=tar --prefix=junk/ HEAD | (cd /var/tmp/ && tar xf -)`
>
> Create a tar archive that contains the contents of the latest commit on the current branch, and extract it in the `/var/tmp/junk` directory.

Just replace `HEAD` with the commit you are interested in (`REV`).